# How can i Search any web sites without typing http:// or www. (like other android browser's)

Tags: android

```
try {
        ourBrowser.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

}
```

this code is ok i know but  how can i search any site without using Http or www ... like other android browser's . example sometime we type Hello and Google give us all hello worlds with link's....... i m new in android world  so  please  developer's help me out....?

i m also tried this `method = ourBrowser.loadUrl("http://google.com"+url);`

Comment: Check this "?q=hi#q=hi".https://www.google.co.in/?q=hi#q=hi

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.cz/search?q=search+term

is the thing you want or use it as intent:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=fish");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i want to open any site within  my own made android  browser....its asking me open the site on other browser..

Comment: Yes, this intent tries system default browser. For you own webView use the loadUrl() method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's what you need ?

```
public void launchUrl(String URL){

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q="+URL));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
```

And you will call it with

```
launchUrl("MysearchExample");
```